# how to get the header files for graphicsmagick

Tags: c++, image, qt, image-processing, graphicsmagick

i am developing an image processing tool using QT. Am new to both QT & graphicsmagick(magick++) c++ library. i have planned to use c++ as my development language. can anyone suggest me how to get the  graphicsmagick header files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You download the graphicsmagick package for your platform from [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/graphicsmagick/files/).

Answer (score 2):

Going to their sourceforge website maybe... http://sourceforge.net/projects/graphicsmagick/files/graphicsmagick/